# Numbering in appendix

Tags: numbering, appendices

When compiling my file, the appendices are not numbered (the sections are though, but they are counting throughout the appendices). Therefore it seems that the chapters are not recognized. In the appendices I use `\chapter`, `\section` and `\subsection` for the headers. Here you can find my code:

```latex
\input{Style} %in the preamble the \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} is used

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
    \input{...}

\tableofcontents
\pdfbookmark[-1]{Contents}{Contents}

\mainmatter
\ChapterInsidePart
    \input{...} 
    \input{...}
    \input{...}

\backmatter
\input{...}

\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix} %I added these lines of code to try and work around the problem. This would not help. 
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{figure}{0} 
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}     
\setcounter{table}{0} 
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}} 
    \input{...}
    \input{...}
    \input{...}
    \input{...}
    \input{...}
\underline{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What is in `\input{style}`? And what should the bunch of `\input` at the bottom do?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a `memoir` document. Drop `\backmatter`, I do not see any reason to use it. It switches off the numbering.

Comment: other document classes (`amsbook` for one) use `\backmatter` to purposefully switch off chapter numbering.  (it's not wanted for a bibliography or index.)  appendices *should* be numbered, so they should never be placed after `\backmatter`.

Comment: How many classes number bibliography or index by default? In `memoir` I just think it confuses most users, thus I recommend no using it.

Comment: i don't know of any, actually, but i haven't really looked.  on the other hand, a question *did* come up about how to deal with a requirement that appendices appear *after* the bibliography; in that case, using `\chapter*` for the bibliography was the only feasible approach, and forget the `\backmatter`.  (actually, `amsbook` bases both index and bibliography titles on `\chapter*`, so the use of `\backmatter` is moot, but it's good for jogging the memory.)

Comment: Thank you so much, \backmatter was indeed the problem. By making my appendices \mainmatter the problem was solved!